# solution for $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^3+2} - \sqrt{x^3-2}$

Tags: limits

Helo

this limite

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^3+2} - \sqrt{x^3-2}$

if I consider that x goes to infinite, this two expressions will be very closely, almost the same. So I consider that first minus second is equal to zero.

Is this a valid solution for this problem?

I know that infinite minus infinite is one indetermination. But to me this is not the same as x ^ 2 minus 2x when x-> infinite.

Edit:
I know other methods to do this limit, and know that the result is 0 too. the question is if this interpretion that I explain is valid. can I always use this method to solve limits look alike ?

Answer (score 4):

**Note :** While your "intuition" may sound sensible, such statements cannot be safely/rigorously made for expressions involving terms like infinity (even if they yield the correct results). The limit is indeed zero. For a rigorous proof, use the hint below.

**Hint :**
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^3+2} - \sqrt{x^3-2} &= \frac{\left(\sqrt{x^3+2} - \sqrt{x^3-2}\right)\left(\sqrt{x^3+2} + \sqrt{x^3-2}\right)}{\sqrt{x^3+2} +\sqrt{x^3-2}} \\ &= \frac{4}{\sqrt{x^3+2} + \sqrt{x^3-2}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $:$ Observe that $\sqrt {x^3+2} - \sqrt {x^3-2} = \frac {4} {\sqrt {x^3+2} + \sqrt {x^3-2}}.$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be:

\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{x^3 +2} - \sqrt{x^3 -2}) = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{3}{2}}\left[(1 + \frac{2}{x^3})^{\frac{1}{2}} - (1 - \frac{2}{x^3})^{\frac{1}{2}}\right] = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{3}{2}}\left[1 + \frac{1}{x^3} - 1 + \frac{1}{x^3}\right] = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} 2x^{-\frac{3}{2}} = 0
\end{equation}

Where I used the Taylor expansion $(1+x)^{\alpha} \sim 1 + \alpha x$